Studying the convergence of a series applying ratio's test
The exercise asks me to study the convergence of the following series $$ \sum \frac{(3n)!}{3^{3n}(n!)^3}.$$

The exercise gives me an indication to calculate $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$. So:
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\frac{(3(n+1))!}{3^{3(n+1)}((n+1)!)^3}}{\frac{(3n)!}{3^{3n}(n!)^3}}=\frac{(3(n+1))!3^{3n}(n!)^3}{(3n)!3^{3(n+1)}((n+1)!)^3}.$$
Let's simplify:
$$\begin{align}\frac{(3(n+1))!}{(3n)!}&=\frac{(3n+3)(3n+2)(3n+1)3n(3n-1)...2·1)}{3n(3n-1)...2·1}\\&=(3n+3)(3n+2)(3n+1)\end{align}$$
$$\frac{3^{3n}}{3^{3(n+1)}}=3^{-3}$$
$$\frac{(n!)^3}{((n+1)!)^3}=\left(\frac{n!}{(n+1)!}\right)^3=\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}$$
Therefore,
$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(3n+3)(3n+2)(3n+1)}{3^3(n+1)^3}=\frac{(3n+2)(3n+1)}{3^2(n+1)^2}=\frac{9n^2+9n+2}{9n^2+18n+9}$

Applying d'Alembert's ratio test:
$$\lim \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim \frac{9n^2+9n+2}{9n^2+18n+9}=1$$
Then the test is inconclusive.

Applying Raabe's test we have:
$$\lim \hspace{5 pt }n \left( 1- \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right)=\lim \hspace{5 pt }n \left( 1- \frac{9n^2+9n+2}{9n^2+18n+9}\right)=\lim \hspace{5 pt }\frac{9n^2+7n}{9n^2+18n+9}=1$$
Then the test is inconclusive.


Is there an error in my reasoning or is convergence studied in another way? I am confused that I am asked to study the quotient but ratio's test and Raabe's test are inconlcusive.

Try Bertrand's test perhaps?

By your own calculations, Raabe's test is conclusive:
$$n\left(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}-1\right)=n\left(\frac{9n^2+18n+9}{9n^2+9n+2}-1\right)=\frac{9n^2+7n}{9n^2+9n+2}<1$$
hence the series is divergent.
